# System.Json missing?

Tags: json, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I recently downloaded and installed the MonoTouch & Mono for Android trial SDKs. Included was MonoDevelop and I use this tool for development. I'm trying to create a multi-platform app.

I'm trying to call a webservice and parse the JSON data that's returned. Somehow it seems the System.JSON library is missing.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or missing something. Anyone got any clue on how to fix this?

**Edit:** I might have to resort [to this project](https://github.com/moljac/System.Json) if System.Json is indeed missing ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel kinda stupid now. I didn't realise I have to add a reference to the System.Json library in my project to make use of it. Since I saw the base System library included, I thought everything else in the System namespace was included by default as well.

Either way, to fix issues like missing assemblies that exist in the framework, just double-click on the `References` folder in your Mono project and select the libraries you want to see included.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Newtonsoft's JSON convert](http://json.codeplex.com/) which has a lot more features that System.Json and also has much better performance characteristics. There is a build of it for Mono that you can use in your project as well.

Comment: Well, I found the solution for my problem, but your answer helped me figure it out. When I tried to add a reference to the Newtonsoft Json library in my project I found out how to include System.Json as well. Therefore you'll get an upvote. Will stick to System.Json for now, as it's part of the BCL and therefore I'll assume it's ready for Windows Phone as well. The Newtonsoft website only claims the library is compatible with MonoTouch & MonoDroid.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured out the problem. Note though that ASP.NET MVC Web API stack, a microsoft product, has abandoned System.Json in favor of JSON.Net! Mono also uses JSON.net code inside their web client implementations for serialization and deserialization, so it's a better choice going forward for you. Checkout the [feature comparison](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll keep this in mind and might consider replacing System.Json for JSON.Net. Would like to know if / when the library will be ready for Windows Phone though, would like to transfer our mobile platform to Mono in the coming year and expand to Windows Phone.

Comment: There's also a PCL Json.Net release - which I've used on MonoTouch, MonoDroid, WP and WinRT - love it (only failed to get it working on PlayStation Vita so far!)